# wpf mvvm accelerator key binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, menu, mvvm-light

I am newbie with WPF and Mvvm, trying to understand the menus with accelerator keys. I have the following xaml. The Help and sub menus H1, H2 work as expected i.e I press Alt + H and then 2, the handler MenuItem_Click_2 gets called. This works fine, but I want to do this with Mvvm. If you see the _View menu(here comes Mvvm), only Alt + V works, and this shows the menu as follows as per the binding with the ViewModel. But further to this, if I type Alt + V and then G or P, it does not work. I guess I am missing something very basic here. What is it?

[image]

Also the _Help works fully is as follows

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="Aitoe.Vigilant.Controller.WpfController.MultiCameraControllerView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Aitoe.Vigilant.Controller.WpfController"
        xmlns:localM="clr-namespace:Aitoe.Vigilant.Controller.WpfController.Model"
        xmlns:localInfra="clr-namespace:Aitoe.Vigilant.Controller.WpfController.Infra"
        xmlns:localCustomControls="clr-namespace:Aitoe.Vigilant.Controller.WpfController.CustomControls"
        xmlns:localV="clr-namespace:Aitoe.Vigilant.Controller.WpfController.Views"
        xmlns:localVM="clr-namespace:Aitoe.Vigilant.Controller.WpfController.ViewModel"
        DataContext="{Binding MultiCameraControllerVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
        mc:Ignorable="d" WindowState="Maximized"
        Title="Aitoe Multi Camera Controller" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="_File"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_View">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding }"
                                        />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Help">
                <MenuItem Header="H_1" Click="MenuItem_Click_1" />
                <MenuItem Header="H_2" Click="MenuItem_Click_2"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1"  Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Controls` have support for `KeyBinding`. For example, `ItemsControl` can have various `KeyBinding's`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FooData}">
        <ItemsControl.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding  Modifiers="Alt" Key="V"  Command="{Binding YourCommand}"/>               
        </ItemsControl.InputBindings>            
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Also you can set multiple modifiers:

```
<KeyBinding Modifiers="Alt+Shift" Key="V" Command="{Binding YourCommand}"/>
```

Comment: I will give it a try and then let you know. Looks simple. Thanks.